# ReactJs TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'name' of object '#<Object>'

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to change the name property of an input as the state of my component changes.
in short, this is What i'm trying to do.

```
 let displayInputElement = (
  <input
    type="text"
    name = {pips}
    placeholder="Type your answer here"
    className=" form-control"
  />
);



 displayInputElement.props.name = "chicken";
```

But I'm getting the below error

> TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'name' of object '#'

Please how can i achieve the below in react

```
displayInputElement.props.name = "chicken";
let pips = displayInputElement.props.name;

displayInputElement = (
  <input
    type="text"
    name = "chicken"
    placeholder="Type your answer here"
    className=" form-control"
  />
);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should make displayInputElement as a component so you can pass whatever you want through the props argument

```
let DisplayInputElement = (props) =>(
  <input
    type="text"
    name = {props.name}
    placeholder="Type your answer here"
    className=" form-control"
  />
);
const state = {
    name:"myrrtle"
}
ReactDOM.render(<DisplayInputElement name={state.name} />, mountNode);
```

You can't set props by writing `DisplayInputElement.props.name="chicken"` as props are meant to be read.
I have just taken an example state to demonstrate what I mean. Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue while working with React State. I have found the simple solution and its worked for me. Just you will have to do a deep copy of your array. It may be enough with:

```
let newData = data.map((item) => 
     Object.assign({}, item, {selected:false})
)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Props are read only.

You can create a new variable with the name prop, then change that variable, or, use a callback to update the parent component's property which can be passed down to this component.

```
let newName = displayInputElement.props.name;
newName = "chicken";
```

Or something like this:

```
this.state = {
  name: this.props.name;
}

this.setState({
 name: "chicken";
}), () => {
  callbackToParent(this.state.name);
}
```